# How to assign 2 bits of 4 bit variable in Verilog HDL?

Tags: verilog

I have an 8-bit input variable "in" and a 4-bit input variable "f". How do I assign the first two bits of "f" to be the first two bits of "in", and the last two bits of "f" to be the last two bits of "in"?

For example if in = 10000011, f = 1011

something like

input [7:0] in;

input [3:0] f;

assign f = {in[1:2], in[7:8]};

The error is "value cannot be assigned to f"

Thanks!

(Verilog HDL, Quartus Prime Lite 20)

Comment: Yes, the error is from compilation

Comment: Notice the ranges are reversed, taking slice`[1:2]` from range `[7:0]` In VHDL that would give empty slices and therefore a length mismatch : does Verilog allow reversing the indexes? Also you probably shouldn't be assigning one input port to another...

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `assign f = {in[0:1], in[6:7]}`.  I'm pretty sure that if you've declared `in` as `in[0:7]` it's not going to have a bit 8.

Comment: I changed f to wire and changed "in" index to [0:7] and now it compiles. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can assign to an **input**. Change `f` to an output or to some kind of local wire type.